# How to restrict width of firetv input for EditText (number password) to 4 characters

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv

Using `android:maxLength="4"` attribute, I am able to restrict the input into 4 digits. But still the input popup in firetv stick shows spaces for 5 digits. Customer is getting confused because of these. Any solution would be appreciated.

[image]

I declared the EditText in layout xml as follows.

```xml
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/pin_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:background="@drawable/ls_edit_text_bg"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:maxLength="4"
            />
```

Comment: android:ems="4" ? Fix the width to be notationally 4 "M" wide as maxLength controls the number of input characters, not the size of the view. Note depending on the font you still might get more than 4 characters unless using a Monospaced font.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this?